# What happens if you connect a surface to ground?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-circuits, charge, potential, conductors

Let's say we have the concentric spherical conductor surfaces, and we connect them to $V_1,V_2,V_3$ respectively, and say we wanted to disconnect the middle one and connect it to the ground such that $V_2'=0$. What will happen to the other electric potentials $V_1', V_3'$? Does something like "conservation of charge" work in here? And also what would happen to the charges? I'm assuming they won't change, or will they?

Comment: You say you're not disconnecting the others from the "batteries" that control their potentials, so they stay at $V_1$ and $V_3$.

Answer (score 1):

It depends entirely on the details of the voltage sources 1 and 3.

If they are near-inexhaustible sources of charge, they may stay at roughly the same voltage, and you'll have a current running from them to ground for as long as that lasts.

If 1 and 3 only have a small amount of charge, that charge will dissipate into ground and the sources will quickly reach 0 V.

The question is the same as asking "What will happen if I open two water lines to the ground?" It will depend on what is at the other end of the lines.